# Particle Emitter 'tap through'

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have created a game where there is are multiple moving nodes named 'xNode' moved via `SKAction.moveByX` and whenever xNode is touched, I will do a `particle.resetSimulation` and the particles will do its thing. However, once the particles is 'emitted', I have a hard time touching other nodes because they are somewhat 'blocking' the node even though I included `userInteractionEnabled = true`. Some help would be appreciated.

```
    for var index = 0; index < 6; index++ {

        particles = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(particlePath!) as! SKEmitterNode
        particles.name = "particles"
        particles.particleAlphaSequence = SKKeyframeSequence(keyframeValues: [1.0, 0.5, 0], times: [0.0, 0.5, 1.0])
        particles.zPosition = 5
        particleArr.append(particles)
        particleHolder.addChild(particleArr[index])
        particleHolder.zPosition = 5
}

if touchedNode?.name == "xNode" {

        particleArr[index].particlePositionRange = CGVectorMake(self.frame.width, (touchedNode?.size.height)!)
        particleArr[index].targetNode = touchedNode
        particleArr[index].position = CGPointMake((touchedNode?.position.x)!, (touchedNode?.position.y)!)
        particleArr[index].resetSimulation()
        particleArr[index].userInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: Like I said in your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565346/how-do-i-touch-a-node-if-it-is-behind-under-another-node, You need to set userInteraction = false to anything that you do not want to be interactive and will end up above things that should be interactive.  You really shouldn't ask 2 questions that are almost identical, perhaps you could have just reworded the question to handle both situations.