# How do I touch a node if it is 'behind/under' another node?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I created a game and there is a node of `SKLabelNode` that tells the user what his current score is. I also have other game nodes of `SKSpriteNode` below the `SKLabelNode` moving around. I am unable to tap on the spritenodes when they are directly under the labelnode even though I have `userInteractionEnabled = true`. The `print` code below never prints anything when I tap on the label. Can someone help me out?

Note: my actual sprites is actually a subclass of `SKSpriteNode`, not sure if it matters.

```
let label = SKLabelNode()
let sprites = SKSpriteNode()

label.text = "\(score)"
label.zPosition = 5
label.userInteractionEnabled = true
label.name = "label"

sprites.zPosition = 4
sprites.name = "sprites"

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
/* Called when a touch begins */

for _ in touches {

    let touch: UITouch = touches.first!

    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
    print(touchedNode.name)

}
}
```

Comment: [This answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26330838/5191756) may point you in the right direction.  Basically, using the `[node containsPoint: location]` might work for you.

Comment: you need to set userInteraction = false on the label

Comment: also, if your sprites are a subclass, then  override the subclasses touchesBegan property

Comment: Try `nodesAtPoint` instead. It provides an array of nodes that intersect the touch location. You can then loop through the nodes and pick the one you're interested in.

Comment: Successfully achieved what I wanted with nodesAtPoint. Thanks!